# Parsing unstructured data to structured data from pdf in R or Python

Tags: python, r, pdf, machine-learning, ocr

I need to read 100 pdf documents, where I need to extract the text information from the pdf and export the excel. In the pdf there are various text from which I need to create the data table. I am giving a part of the pdf from which I need to extract the information.

```
I am doing my job in the company(Employee Id : 12345678)
Name : XXXXX YYYYY
** Date of Birth : 12/12/2001**
** Place : AAAAAAAA**
** Address: 111, BLOCK 1,**
** XYZ LOCALITY**
** BANGKOK **
** Email id: xyz@yahoo.in**
```

I have to create the columns and extract all the information along with it from all the pdfs in Excel.
I am trying to use tesseract and pdf_convert.

My output should be like:

```
Date              Address         Place 
12/12/2001       XYZ Locality    AAAAAAA
                  bangkok
```

Comment: Can you please use `dput` to show the example as it is not clear. Do you have `**` etc in your input

Comment: What specifically do you need help with? If it's everything then we'd be doing your job for you.

Comment: akrun: ** is not the input

Comment: Rohit: I am not getting the function to parse the data next to the fields in pdf, it is a small part of the work, Its a kinda big project, just while parsing I got stuck....!!

Comment: Could you provid an example of PDF document? That would be helpful to provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach that can be considered :

```
library(stringr)

text_Vector <- c("** Date of Birth : 12/12/2001**",
                 "** Place : AAAAAAAA**",
                 "** Address: 111, BLOCK 1,**",
                 "** XYZ LOCALITY**",
                 "** BANGKOK **",
                 "** Email id: xyz@yahoo.in**")

text_Vector_One_Line <- paste0(text_Vector, collapse = "")
text_Splitted <- stringr::str_split(text_Vector_One_Line, "(\\*\\*\\*\\*)|(\\*\\*)")[[1]]
text_Splitted <- text_Splitted[text_Splitted != ""]

list_Text <- list()
nb_Token <- length(text_Splitted)
counter <- 1

for(i in 1 : nb_Token)
{
  if(stringr::str_detect(text_Splitted[i], ":") == TRUE)
  {
    list_Text[[counter]] <- text_Splitted[i]
    counter <- counter + 1
  }else
  {
    list_Text[[counter - 1]] <- paste0(list_Text[[counter - 1]], text_Splitted[i], collapse = "")
  }
}

list_Text <- lapply(X = list_Text, FUN = function(x) strsplit(x, ":")[[1]])
first_Col <- unlist(lapply(X = list_Text, FUN = function(x) x[1]))
second_Col <- unlist(lapply(X = list_Text, FUN = function(x) x[2]))

cbind(first_Col, second_Col)

first_Col         second_Col                            
[1,] " Date of Birth " " 12/12/2001"                         
[2,] " Place "         " AAAAAAAA"                           
[3,] " Address"        " 111, BLOCK 1, XYZ LOCALITY BANGKOK "
[4,] " Email id"       " xyz@yahoo.in"
```